# IntelliTrace Historical Debugging does not jump in Click-EventHandler

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, intellitrace

I have created a small WPF-Application with one Button and a Label. The Click-Eventhandler of the Button do

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var s = this.Height;
    this.lbl.Content = s;
}
```

I have activated IntelliTrace Event collecting. When I run debug and click on the Button, I see in the IntelliTrace-Event-List the corresponding events:
[image]

When I click on "Activate Historical Debugging" Visual Studio shows the following:
[image]

and this StackTrace:
[image]

Why can I not jump to the EventHandler Button_Click() now?

Comment: Just view your debug modules window, and check that whether all assemblies are loaded, as the messages, it means that it couldn't find and load the pdb file during debugging time. Maybe you could try to delete this reference in your project, and then re-add it again, Please also change .net framework version, clean and rebuild your app, and then enable the Microsoft Symbols Servers, debug it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Please enable the Microsoft symbol servers under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols.

(2) Check "Enable .NET Framework source stepping" and "Enable source serve support" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging.

[image]

(3) Under your project properties->Debug, disable the option "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process", and enable the option "Enable native code debugging".

And then debug your app with breakpoint, view the result.
[image]

**Update:**

The button click event in the intellitrace log is not what you thinks it is. It’s not tracing your code, it’s tracing the presentation framework. Intellitrace knows nothing about the event handler.

However, you can achieve what you wants by using a tracepoint in your event handler.

Comment: The Problem is, that I do not want to skip in PresentationFramework but in the EventHandler which is my code. This is loaded correct. When I put a breakpoint and do "normal" Debugging, it is working perfect.

Comment: @BennoDual, maybe you could share us much more information about what you mean "I do not want to skip in PresentationFramework but in the EventHandler", in addition, I will share the result I got in my side after I enable certain debugging settings in my side, if possible, you could use the same settings and debug it again. I will edit my previous answer.

Comment: here is a Link to a ScreenCast which shows my problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t45huh705o9rvbo/IntelliTraceScreenCast.mp4?dl=0 When I click the Button it jumps to the Breakpoint in my Click-EventHandler. This is ok. But When I activate Historical Debugging, it does not jump into my Click-Eventhandler.

Comment: @BennoDual, the real issue is that it needs to step into the .NET Framework source code with this step, since you didn't enable the .NET Framework debugging, so you would get the warning without the PresentationFramework .pdb file, actually I get the source not available in my side if I enable the option 1 and option 2 in my previous answer. But my understanding is that the real issue is that I have no the source code for .net framework assembly.

Comment: I will download it and test it in my side:https://referencesource.microsoft.com/download.html, if possible, you could also try to test it in your side.

Comment: I understand the issue about the source for PresentationFramework.pdb. But I do not want to debug PresentationFramework.pdb - i want debug only my code (the click-handler).

Comment: @BennoDual, Sorry for my delay, I just update my previous answer with an update for this issue.