# No locals available in historical debugging on exception in async methods (VS2017)

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I am just wondering if there is a way to view locals when an exception is thrown in async methods. In the locals tab I can only see the exception details but no locals around where the exception is thrown. Can I get some locals as well in historical debugging?

[image]
[image]

Here is a sketch of the code I am using:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public Updater Updater { get; set; } = new Updater();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Updater.TickerList.Add("MSFT");
    }

    private async void UpdateButtonOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Updater.UpdateDaily("MSFT");
    }
}

public class Updater()
{
    public async Task<bool> UpdateDaily(string ticker, bool full = false)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the main code in your issue? So we could also repro this issue? Whether the breakpoint was hit in your side? If you use other debugging window like Watch windows, could you visit certain variable value in your side?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is a bit hard to share the code since it is a big project and isolating the code that brings up the issue would be hard. I added a sketch of the code that I am using in the main question and I can add details if you need any. I will answer your questions:

The breakpoint was hit locally. The watch window shows me [Available intellitrace data is shown in the Locals window]. I am working with a WPF project.

Comment: Like this case I met beforehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796916/intellitrace-historical-debugging-does-not-jump-in-click-eventhandler, the real issue is what the intellitrace log collected: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx, if you really want to catch the exception information like the line code or others, why not use the exception settings in your side?